# Duvida logica do calculo C#

Tags: c#

Estou estudando C# e criei as seguintes rotinas.

```
   public class ContaCorrente
   {
    
    private double double_Saldo = 100;
    public double double_SaldoNovoDeposito;

        public double Func_ConsultaSaldo()
        {
            return this.double_Saldo;
        }

        public double Func_DepositarMinhaConta(double double_ValorDeposito)
        {
            double_SaldoNovoDeposito = double_Saldo += double_ValorDeposito;
            return double_ValorDeposito;
        }

        public double Func_ConsulNovoSaldo()
        {
            return double_SaldoNovoDeposito[![inserir a descrição da imagem aqui][1]][1];
        }
    }
```

Com este metodos gostaria de consulta um saldo que neste caso o default e 100 e depositara 200 o que esta ok e retornar o novo valor da conta pela Func_ConsulNovoSaldo  porém esta apanes me retorna 100 no caso o valor padrao da variavel.

No arquivo Program estou fazendo a seguinte execução.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ContaCorrente contaSaldo = new ContaCorrente();            
        Console.WriteLine(contaSaldo.Func_ConsultaSaldo());

        ContaCorrente contaValorDeposito = new ContaCorrente();
        Console.WriteLine(contaValorDeposito.Func_DepositarMinhaConta(200));

        ContaCorrente contaNovoSaldo = new ContaCorrente();
        Console.WriteLine(contaNovoSaldo.Func_ConsulNovoSaldo());

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Poderiam me ajudar onde estou errando, pois as duas primeiras rotinas retorna o valor correto 100 (o padrao) e 200 (o valor depositado) porém gostaria de somar o valor "velho ao novo".

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Comment: `ContaCorrente contaSaldo = new ContaCorrente();` a cada vez que executa esse comando, uma nova instância da classe é criada, ou seja, `double_Saldo` será iniciada com o valor de 100.  Deve fazer métodos que façam manutenção na mesma variável, ou seja, os métodos que mudam o saldo deveriam retornar `double_Saldo`. Não é preciso por prefixos nos membros da classe (variáveis e métodos), use simplemente `private double saldo = 100;` e `public double DepositarMinhaConta(double valorDeposito)`

Answer (score 1):

Como o coloega comentou... você está criando novas instâncias e por isso valor sempre volta ao default. Assim como não há nenhuma necessidade de existir um método consulta para consultar o novo saldo.

```
   static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ContaCorrente contaCorrente = new ContaCorrente();
           
        Console.WriteLine(contaCorrente.Func_ConsultaSaldo());

        Console.WriteLine(contaCorrente.Func_DepositarMinhaConta(200));

        Console.WriteLine(contaCorrente.Func_ConsultaSaldo());

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Vi que você está criando objetos diferentes e alterando eles sem conexão alguma entre si, tente compreender se você está tentando fazer isso da forma que você espera: [OBJETOS EM C#](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/tutorials/classes).

Sugestão de simplificação e correção do processo de manipulação de uma conta corrente:

```
//CLASSE:
public class ContaCorrente
{

    // Inicializando com valor padrão
    private double double_Saldo = 100; 

    public double Func_ConsultaSaldo()
    {
        return this.double_Saldo;
    }

    public double Func_DepositarMinhaConta(double double_ValorDeposito)
    {
        this.double_Saldo += double_ValorDeposito;
        return double_ValorDeposito;
    }
}

//ROTINAS:
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ContaCorrente minhaConta = new ContaCorrente();
        Console.WriteLine("SALDO ATUAL: R$" + minhaConta.Func_ConsultaSaldo()); // Consulta saldo atual
        Console.WriteLine("DEPOSITANDO: R$" +  minhaConta.Func_DepositarMinhaConta(200)); // Despositando na mesma conta
        Console.WriteLine("SALDO ATUAL: R$" + minhaConta.Func_ConsultaSaldo()); // Consulta saldo atual
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Nessa solução você resolve tudo, tendo em mãos uma única conta corrente só e podendo depositar e consultar o saldo nela mesma, durante todas as suas rotinas.

A classe ContaCorrente que você criou deve manipular seu próprio saldo, portanto não deve existir uma variável como 'novoSaldo', porque o novo saldo é resultado automático de suas ações de depósito e saque dessa mesma conta.

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).